# Best optimization technique for solving overdetermined systems with a constraint

Tags: optimization, svd, regularization, cvx, model-predictive-control

I am trying to make a prediction model based on a system of linear equations: $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$, where $\vec{x}$ ($m\times1$) is my learning parameters, $A (m\times n)$ and $\vec{b}$ $(m\times1)$ are known measurements from the training experiment. The system is overdetermined ($m>n$). To do this, I minimize $||A\vec{x}-\vec{b}||_2$. The best way I found so far is truncated SVD: making SVD of $A$, getting rid of small singular values and finding solution as $\vec{x}=V\Sigma_{truncated}U^T\vec{b}$. The optimum number of truncation is determined by testing some dataset and minimizing RMSE. My best SVD solution gives me some components of $\vec{x}$ pivoting around zero, something like this: $\vec{x}=||0; 0.1; 0.3; -0.4; 0.2; -0.1; -0.3; 0.4; -0.25...||$ (totally I have 36 values)

So far so good, but I have to constrain my solutions $\vec{x}$ to only positive values. I tried to use CVX toolbox in Matlab for that, but with no luck: the solution simply ends up in $\vec{x}$ with all zero components except one ($\vec{x}=||0; 0; 0;...1||$). RMSE of such solution is several orders of magnitude higher than that of the optimum SVD. For some prediciting sense of my model, I would expect to get at least several positive components in my solution (the most important characteristics of the system). Here is what I am doing with CVX in Matlab. Unfortunately, I cannot give you the matrix $A$ and $\vec{b}$, since it is confidential.

```
cvx_begin
variable x(n)
minimize norm(A*x-b)
subject to
x >= 0
cvx_end
```

Does the experts know a better optimization tool?

Comment: Show us what you did with CVX, preferably with a minimum reproducible example.  What specifically didn't you "like"about the solution obtained with CVX? Do you have in mind a "better" (in some sense which you will tell us) solution than what was obtained with CVX?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, I edited the question

Comment: You have computed the nonnegative least squares solution using CVX. The "optimum" SVD is not optimal for your problem because it is not feasible. Presumably, the SVD solution has one or more `x` components which are negative. If you re-run CVX, but without `x >= 0`, the optimal objective value should match what you got by SVD, but it would have one or more `x` components which are negative.  If you think your model makes lousy predictions, then maybe you have a lousy model.

Comment: @baronett The optimization problem is convex, so the optimal solution is global. Even when you constrain $x$ to be nonnegative, the solution you are getting still is the best you can get with this constraint. You will never be able to obtain better with any other method. The problem comes from the data, not the mathematical/computational approach you are using.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, that's actually not exactly true. Without the constraint, CVX gives the solution, coinciding with the solution for SVD with ALL (no truncation) singular values. As I said before, the best solution I got when truncating some singular values. Also, I know that if I manually leave only some 2 or 3 non-zero positive components of $\vec{x}$ (which would correspond to the most affecting parameters in my system), I will get a better prediction than by CVX in terms of RMSE. I wonder why I cannot at least get these intutitive solutions by CVX.

Comment: @KBS, I know that if I manually leave only some 2 or 3 non-zero positive components of $\vec{x}$ (which would correspond to the most affecting parameters in my system), I will get a better prediction than by CVX in terms of RMSE. So it seems, that CVX doesn't give me the global optimum

Comment: @baronett CVX globally minimizes the cost under the nonnegativity constraint because the problem is convex. If you do not observe that, there is a problem somewhere.